# What is max size for a Uint8Array in IE11(32bit)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, typedarray

i tried "new Unint8Array(1475328486)" and it returned "invalid typed array length" exception

Is too long size ??

My environments are window7(64bit) , 4GB Memory, Internet Explore 11(may be 32bit, i tried start with 64bit but it always start 32bit )

Comment: Yes, an "*invalid typed array length*" `RangeError` means that the size is too large.

Comment: @Bergi or too small (-1)